# Prove propositional formula is a theorem

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I need to show this formula is a theorem of propositional calculus. I tried assuming antecedent and proving consequent but didn't work for this proof. Do I need to show it is equivalent to true? How should I start?

$(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow (p \wedge r \rightarrow q \wedge r)$

Background:

In my class, there is no mention to it but I think this form of logic it's called Equational Logic. This is a sample demonstration.

[image: Sample Demonstration]

Comment: Are you supposed to show it's a theorem in a particular formalization of propositional logic? If so, anyone answering this will need to know which formalization you want. If the question isn't tied to a particular formalization, you could just write out the 8-line truth-table for your formula. Or you could analyze what a truth assignment would have to do in order to falsify the formula (and ultimtely show that such falsification is impossible).

Comment: Thank you. I will add background information. I think it's called Equational Logic.

Comment: See David Gries & Fred Schneider, [A Logical Approach to Discrete Math (Springer, 1993)](https://books.google.it/books?id=103UBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), page 70.

Comment: Thank you Mauro Allegranza. And based on your recommendation on another answer, I’m enjoying Mathematical Logic by Tourlakis. Unfortunately, in those books there are not solved exercises; only worked examples. And when I try to do my class problems, I struggle. Do you have more basic books of resources to recommend? Can you give me a hint on the first problem I posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to use the proof system of David Gries & Fred Schneider, [A Logical Approach to Discrete Math (Springer, 1993)](https://books.google.it/books?id=103UBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), we can mimick the proof of (4.2), page 70 :

> We begin with the consequent : $(p ∧ r \Rightarrow  q ∧ r)$, since it has more structure, and transform it into the antecedent : $p \Rightarrow q$. Keeping in mind the goal, the first step is to eliminate the implication. Any of the four "definitions" of implication (3.57), (3.59), (3.60), and (3.61) could be used for this.

We have to use (3.60) : $(\alpha \Rightarrow \beta) \equiv (\alpha \land \beta \equiv \alpha)$ to get :

> $$(p \land r) \land (q \land r) \equiv p \land r.$$

Using Idempotency, Associativity and Simmetry we get :

> $$r \land (p \land q) \equiv r \land p.$$

Now we use (3.62) : $\alpha \Rightarrow (\beta \equiv \gamma) \equiv (\alpha \land \beta) \equiv (\alpha \land \gamma)$, to get :

> $$r \Rightarrow ((p \land q) \equiv p).$$

Now we use (4.1) : $\alpha  \Rightarrow  (\beta \Rightarrow \alpha )$ to derive (this is **not** an equivalence but $\Leftarrow$) :

> $$(p \land q) \equiv p.$$

The last step uses again (3.60) to conclude with :

> $$p \Rightarrow q.$$

In conclusion, we have :

> > $(p ∧ r \Rightarrow  q ∧ r) \Leftarrow (p \Rightarrow q):$

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you explain this step? (this is not an equivalence but ⇐). How did you remove variable **r**?.

Comment: @F.Zer - it is Modus Ponens applied to the tautology : $\alpha \to (\beta \to \alpha)$. We use the instance : $((p∧q)≡p) ⇒ [r ⇒ ((p∧q)≡p)]$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand a little more but not fully, yet. How did you use 4.1 to derive ((∧)≡)⇒[⇒((∧)≡)] ? I didn’t know you could replace an expression with an implication in that way. And Modus Ponens uses P => Q and P to conclude Q. What is your instance of this rule?